# Can full rank matrix have zero determinant?

Tags: inverse, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

all.

Let ***A*** be a real symmetric $(N\times N)$ matrix.

Although I would like to check its rank and determinant in order to calculate the inverse of ***A***, a confliction arised. $\\$ Since ***A*** is a large matrix, (I wish I could break the matrix in several small pieces and have a look), I checked the rank and the determinant through MATLAB.

Though the rank is *N*, the determinant is equal to 0.

```
>> rank(A)
ans = N

>> det(A)
ans = 0

>> cond(A)
ans = 5.2e+05
```

As far as I know that the full rank is identical to be invertable, but it cannot since the determinant is zero. How it can be resolved? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, the condition that $A$ has rank $n$ is equivalent to $\det A\ne0$. Another equivalent condition is that $A$ is invertible. Apparently there are rounding problems.

Comment: The large condition number suggests that your matrix is very close to a matrix that does not have full rank (which makes it appear that A has full rank but also zero determinant).

Comment: If your matrix coefficients are small, even though the matrix has full rank, the determinant can underflow. (Scaling the elements by $s$ scales the determinant by $s^n$.

Comment: It is possible that $\det$ underflows, but the matrix is still well conditioned. See https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1330.

Comment: @YvesDaoust less than 1% of the elements in ***A*** is equal to zero, the others are non-zero elements, and the maximum is less than 0.05. It seems ***A*** has very small values. Even I simply multiply a constant, $c$, to ***A***, it seems not to work well. Can I know how to scale the matrix ***A***?

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you! I'll have a look! The question seems quite similar to my case.

Comment: @Creatlee: how much is $N$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust $N$ is 1280, I just checked the condition number and the determinant. $\det(cA)$ suddenly gives the answer Inf while changing $c$ gradually.

Comment: @Creatlee: of course, $c$ is raised to the power 1280 !

Answer (score 1):

The condition number of a matrix, cond(A), measures the sensitivity to changes in the input.  Since your matrix has a large condition number, the true value of the determinant could be very different than 0.  (Or possibly the matrix may not be full rank).  See the [Matlab Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cond.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Though I've already checked the link from the MATLAB documentation, there seems no helpful information for this case. But I appreciate to you! :)